# When does convolution create turning points?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convolution

Suppose $f$ and $k$ are Lebesgue measurable functions $\mathbf R\to\mathbf R$ and satisfy $k(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$, and $\int_{\mathbf R} k(x)\,dx=1$. Also suppose $f$ has bounded variation, and $f(-\infty)=0$ and $f(\infty)=1$. Let $$(k*f)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}k(x-y)f(y)dy$$ denote the convolution of $k$ and $f$.

Let $TP(f)$ denote the number of turning points of a measurable function. We can define turning points like follows: let $P=\{a=x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n=b\}$ be a partition of $\mathbf R$. Then we can define
$$ D(f; P) = \left\{ f(x_1)-f(x_0),\dots, f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1}) \right\}$$

$$ TP(f) = \sup_P (\# \text{sign changes of }D(f; P))$$

**My question:** When does $k*f$ have more turning points than $f$? Equivalently, under what conditions will $k*f$ have *at most* as many turnings points as $f$?

Since $f$ has bounded variation we know that $TP(f)$ is at most countably infinite. But consider an example like the Gaussian kernel, especially in the context of heat flow. It is intuitively obvious that heat flow will not create new turning points. I cannot seem to prove this in the language of functional analysis.

---

It is easy to show $(k*f)(-\infty)=0$ and $(k*f)(\infty)=1$, and also that the variation of $k*f$ is not greater than the variation of $f$.

ALso, if $f$ has no turning points then neither does $k*f$, because if $f$ is monotone then the variation of $f$ is $1$, and if $k*f$ has a turning point then its variation is strictly greater than $1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Convolutions do not always smooth. Consider convolving with something that looks like $[1,1,1,-1,-1,-1]$. This behaves like a (low pass) derivative , and may cause functions such as $x+\epsilon \sin(x)$ to become more or less $1+\epsilon \cos(x)$ with an infinite number of turning points.

Comment: @user619894 I specified that $k(x)$ is non-negative. However even this condition is not enough. My next best guess is $|x|\leq|y|\implies k(x)\geq k(y)$ which enforces that $k$ is not bimodal or something (assuming wlog $\int xk(x)dx=0$).

Comment: By "turning point" do you mean local maximums and minimums?

Comment: @GregMartin I added a better definition of turning points that doesn't rely on differentiability. I think it should work as long as $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: In your definition, since presumably $x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n$, it's clearer to define $D(f;P)$ using only the numerators. Otherwise I'm happy with that definition (although I'll point out that the definition of local maximums/minimums has nothing to do with differentiability).

Comment: I found this mention that decreasing turning points suggests the $k$ must be Gaussian https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186083/maximum-of-a-mollified-convolution-function

Comment: Shouldn't a more likely conjecture be $TP(k*f) \le \max\{TP(f),TP(k)\}$? I know there are some slight differences between the assumptions on $k$ and $f$, but morally speaking convolution doesn't know which function we've deemed the kernel.

Comment: @GregMartin  For my application $TP(k)=1$ so that statement would be just as good.